# Struggling with file types for animation render

Tags: animation

I'd like to render an animation I've designed in F360. The file type is avi which Blender doesn't support ( I don't think)!
I've followed a tutorial and converted the file to mp4 but still can't get it to work.
Is there a way around this? 
Any help much appreciated.

Philip.
p.s Bear in mind I'm new to all this so might struggle a bit with trade jargon.

Comment: Blender should support both AVI and MP4, not sure what the issue really is

Comment: Maybe you should just start by watching an introduction to the VSE like the one from [Mikeycal Meyers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4)?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, my mistake re the file support. I have gone through the tutorials and managed to open my file in blender.